# *ngIf does not Set Variable Properly

Tags: html, angular, set

I've been trying to set a variable but it is not rendering on HTML. Here's a simple example:

```
 <div *ngIf="'hello world'; let testVariable">{{testVariable}}</div>
```

However, the testVairable does not show up on HTML, but instead, the Elements in the inspect printed this:

[image]

I have another  statement and it is rendering properly. The `document` variable is from the backend so this statement does not involve any variable setter:

```
 <div *ngIf="document.story_summary " [innerHTML]="document.story_summary"></div>
```

I was wondering if there's any syntax that I miss?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your syntax. You need to put the testVariable first in your **ngIf*, if not, it will always set as true. Also, *ngIfElse* accepts template instead of just a string, so you need to add a template to cater for your else. See the code below:

```
<div *ngIf="testVariable; else hello_world">{{testVariable}}</div>
<ng-template #hello_world>hello world...</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I got an error using your solution saying: Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Comment: You need to add BrowserModule in your imports on your module.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an issue in your syntax your html format should be like this 
`<div *ngIf="testVariable; else hello_world">{{testVariable}}</div>`

`<ng-template #hello_world>hello world...</ng-template>` 
else part will be working in `<ng-template>else part</ng-template>`